# The semantics of v8::ResourceConstraints?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

The `v8::ResourceConstraints` class is defined as follows:

```
class V8EXPORT ResourceConstraints {
 public:
  ResourceConstraints();
  int max_young_space_size() const { return max_young_space_size_; }
  void set_max_young_space_size(int value) { max_young_space_size_ = value; }
  int max_old_space_size() const { return max_old_space_size_; }
  void set_max_old_space_size(int value) { max_old_space_size_ = value; }
  int max_executable_size() { return max_executable_size_; }
  void set_max_executable_size(int value) { max_executable_size_ = value; }
  uint32_t* stack_limit() const { return stack_limit_; }
  // Sets an address beyond which the VM's stack may not grow.
  void set_stack_limit(uint32_t* value) { stack_limit_ = value; }
 private:
  int max_young_space_size_;
  int max_old_space_size_;
  int max_executable_size_;
  uint32_t* stack_limit_;
};
```

Can someone tell me what `young_space_size`, `old_space_size`, and `max_executable_size` are? What are their units, how are they related, etc.? There doesn't seem to be much documentation.

Also, how does one use the `stack_limit` property? For example, if I want my V8 isolate to use no more than 1MB of stack space, how would I calculate a pointer value for `stack_limit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v8/test/cctest/test-api.cc uses this function to calculate the limit:

```
// Uses the address of a local variable to determine the stack top now.
// Given a size, returns an address that is that far from the current
// top of stack.
static uint32_t* ComputeStackLimit(uint32_t size) {
  uint32_t* answer = &size - (size / sizeof(size));
  // If the size is very large and the stack is very near the bottom of
  // memory then the calculation above may wrap around and give an address
  // that is above the (downwards-growing) stack.  In that case we return
  // a very low address.
  if (answer > &size) return reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(sizeof(size));
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Nice find. Thank you!