# How can I create another thread in the v8

Tags: c++, v8

I want to set timeout for v8::Script::Run. Unfortunately,I have a little experience with v8. I understood that I need to use StartPreemtion + Loker + TerminateException. Consequently, v8::Script::Run should be in a separate thread. Calculation and control of the execution time should be in the main thread. How can I create another thread in the v8?. Please help me to understand how to do it. 
Here is an example of the code as I do it, but the function of the thread doesn't start.

```
  v8::Local<v8::Value> V8ExecuteString( v8::Handle<v8::String> source, v8::Handle<v8::String> filename )
  {
     // Compiling script
     // ...
     // End compiling script
     DWORD start_tick = ::GetTickCount();
     v8::Locker::StartPreemption( 1 );
     { 
        v8::Unlocker unlocker;
         boost::thread* th = new boost::thread( [&] () {
           v8::Locker locker;
           v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
           // Running script
           // v8::Script::Run()
           // End running script
        });
     }
    // Calculation and control of the execution time
    v8::Locker locker;
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
    while ( true )
    {
      // terminate thread after 10 seconds
      if( ( (::GetTickCount() - start_tick) / 1000 ) > 10 )
        // v8::v8::TerminateException(  )
    }
    v8::Locker::StopPreemption();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this V8 bug report](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=729), `StartPreemption()` is not reliable currently. However, you don't need it to implement a script execution timeout. This program demonstrates a way:

```
#include "v8.h"
#include "ppltasks.h"

void main(void)
{
    auto isolate = v8::Isolate::New();
    {
        v8::Locker locker(isolate);
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);
        v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
        auto context = v8::Context::New();
        {
            v8::Context::Scope contextScope(context);
            auto script = v8::Script::Compile(v8::String::New("while(true){}"));

            // terminate script in 5 seconds
            Concurrency::create_task([isolate]
            {
                Concurrency::wait(5000);
                v8::V8::TerminateExecution(isolate);
            });

            // run script
            script->Run();
        }
        context.Dispose();
    }
    isolate->Dispose();
}
```

The timer implementation here is obviously suboptimal and specific to Windows Concurrency Runtime, but it's just an example. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me. Do you understand how ResourceConstraints works?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583446/the-semantics-of-v8resourceconstraints. I need to limit the memory script.I understood that there isn't other possibility